# How to setup completion of environment variable names in zsh?

Tags: environment-variables, zsh, zsh-completion

In bash when I try to use autocompletion in double-quoted strings it works:

E.g.

```sh
echo "My home directory is $HO<t>"
# expands to
echo "My home directory is $HOME"
```

But when I try the same thing in zsh it just does nothing.

At the same time it works outside strings:

```
echo My\ home\ directory\ is\ $HO<t>
# expands to
echo My\ home\ directory\ is\ $HOME
```

Is it possible to make it work the same as bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons why this doesn't work for you:

- You need to have the following in your `.zshrc` file:

  ```bash
  autoload -Uz compinit
  compinit
  bindkey '\t' complete-word
  ```

  Without it, the Zsh line editor will simply *expand* the current expression on the line — and will try completion only if that doesn't do anything (which is why your second example does succeed).
- Zsh completion [has a bug](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2021/msg01047.html) where completion of parameter names fails if a partial parameter name is followed by a `"`.

As a workaround:

1. Make sure you're using the code from the first bullet point.
2. When you want to complete a parameter this way, first remove the final `"` from your string before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not using closing `"` doesn't help me. Zsh just converts string `"My home is $HO` to `My\ home\ is\ `.

Comment: It appears you also need to have `bindkey '\t' complete-word` in your `.zshrc` file. I updated my answer.